# SmartGWt open listgrid field to edit on click

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

i am using smartGWT listGrid with customized and not customized  cells, 
on every customized cell i added an image and i want the fields to be also editable, when i click on one of the customized fields the field did not open to edit, and the only way i can access it is to click on non customized  field and move using tab button to the customized one.
the problem is just on fierFox and chrome , but on IE every thing works perfectly.

```
   private ListGrid initializeAndGetSubstratesIndividualListgrid(){
        substratesIndividualListgrid = new ListGrid(true){
            @Override
            protected boolean canEditCell(int rowNum, int colNum) {
                if(this.getFieldNum(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_CONVENTIONAL_INDIVIDUAL) == colNum ||
                        this.getFieldNum(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_NAME) == colNum ||
                        this.getFieldNum(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_SUITABLE_FOR_IN_LINE_PRIMING_INDIVIDUAL) == colNum ||
                        ((this.getFieldNum(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_HP_FOR_ALL_DISCREAT_INDIVIDUAL) == colNum)
                                && LabelsSubstratesViewImpl.this.isCanOpenIndividual(getRecord(rowNum)) ))

                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            protected Canvas createRecordComponent(final ListGridRecord record, final Integer colNum) {

                String fieldName = this.getFieldName(colNum);
                if (fieldName.equals(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_HP_FIXED_COST_INDIVIDUAL)) {
                    HLayout hpfixedcostHlayout = new HLayout();
                    fixedCostImg = new LabelSubstratesIndividualListGridRadioButton();
                    if(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID) >=0){
                        fixedCostHashMap.put(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID), fixedCostImg);

                    }else{
                        fixedCostHashMap.put(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_GROUPING_INDEX_INDIVIDUAL), fixedCostImg);
                    }

                    fixedCostImg.setTop(4);
                    fixedCostImg.setLeft(4);

                    myLabel fixedCostLabel= new myLabel();
                    fixedCostLabel.setWidth(90);
                    fixedCostLabel.setHeight(22);
                    fixedCostLabel.setTop(1);
                    fixedCostLabel.setLeft(21);

                    hpfixedcostHlayout.addChild(fixedCostImg);
                    hpfixedcostHlayout.addChild(fixedCostLabel);
                    hpfixedcostHlayout.setSize("60px", "24px");
                    fixedCostImg.getImg().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                            ClientFactoryImpl.setDirty(true);
                            if(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID) >=0){
                                primingFactorHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)).unSelectRadio();
                                discreatHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)).unSelectRadio();
                            }else{
                                primingFactorHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_GROUPING_INDEX_INDIVIDUAL)).unSelectRadio();
                                discreatHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_GROUPING_INDEX_INDIVIDUAL)).unSelectRadio();
                            }
                            calculatehpCostIndividual(record);
                            record.setAttribute(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_SELECTEDRADIO, 3);
                        }
                    });
                    for(int i=0; i<this.getRecords().length; i++){
                        if(fillFixedCostHashMap.get(i)== record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)){
                            fixedCostHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)).selectRadio();
                        }
                    }
                    return hpfixedcostHlayout;

                }   else if (fieldName.equals(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_HP_PRIMING_FACTOR_INDIVIDUAL)) {
                    HLayout primingFactorHlayout = new HLayout();
                    primingFactorImg = new LabelSubstratesIndividualListGridRadioButton();

                    if(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID) >=0){
                        primingFactorHashMap.put(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID), primingFactorImg);
                    }else{
                        primingFactorHashMap.put(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_GROUPING_INDEX_INDIVIDUAL), primingFactorImg);// -1 if the record index is the same as exested record id
                    }

                    primingFactorImg.setTop(4);
                    primingFactorImg.setLeft(4);

                    myLabel primingFactorLabel = new myLabel();
                    primingFactorLabel.setWidth(90);
                    primingFactorLabel.setHeight(22);
                    primingFactorLabel.setTop(1);
                    primingFactorLabel.setLeft(21);

                    primingFactorHlayout.addChild(primingFactorImg);
                    primingFactorHlayout.addChild(primingFactorLabel);
                    primingFactorHlayout.setSize("60px", "24px");
                    primingFactorImg.getImg().addClickHandler( new ClickHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                            ClientFactoryImpl.setDirty(true);
                            if(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID) >=0){
                                discreatHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)).unSelectRadio();
                                fixedCostHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)).unSelectRadio();
                            }else{
                                discreatHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_GROUPING_INDEX_INDIVIDUAL)).unSelectRadio();
                                fixedCostHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_GROUPING_INDEX_INDIVIDUAL)).unSelectRadio();
                            }
                            calculatehpCostFromPrimingFactorIndividual(record);
                            record.setAttribute(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_SELECTEDRADIO, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    for(int i=0; i<this.getRecords().length; i++){
                        if(fillFactorHashMap.get(i) == record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)){
                            primingFactorHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)).selectRadio();
                        }
                    }
                    return primingFactorHlayout;
                }else if (fieldName.equals(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_HP_FOR_ALL_DISCREAT_INDIVIDUAL)) {

                    HLayout discreatHlayout = new HLayout();
                    discreatImg = new LabelSubstratesIndividualListGridRadioButton();
                    discreatImg.setTop(4);
                   if(Utils.isIE())
                    discreatImg.setLeft(-20);
                   else{
                       discreatImg.setZIndex(100000000);
                       discreatImg.setLeft(-1);
                   }
                    if(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID) >=0){
                        discreatHashMap.put(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID), discreatImg);
                    }else{
                        discreatHashMap.put(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_GROUPING_INDEX_INDIVIDUAL), discreatImg);// -1 if the record index is the same as exested record id
                    }

                    discreatImg.getImg().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                            ClientFactoryImpl.setDirty(true);
                            if(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID) >=0){
                                primingFactorHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)).unSelectRadio();
                                fixedCostHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)).unSelectRadio();
                            }else{
                                primingFactorHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_GROUPING_INDEX_INDIVIDUAL)).unSelectRadio();
                                fixedCostHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_GROUPING_INDEX_INDIVIDUAL)).unSelectRadio();
                            }

                            substratesIndividualListgrid.startEditing(substratesIndividualListgrid.getRecordIndex(record));
                            record.setAttribute(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_HP_FOR_ALL_DISCREAT_INDIVIDUAL, substratesGroupsListgrid.getRecord(substratesIndividualListgrid.getRecordIndex(record)).getAttribute(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_HP_FOR_ALL_DISCREAT) );
                            if(Utils.isIE()){
                            substratesIndividualListgrid.discardEdits(substratesIndividualListgrid.getRecordIndex(record),1);
                            substratesIndividualListgrid.discardEdits(substratesIndividualListgrid.getRecordIndex(record),2);
                            }

                            substratesGroupsListgrid.getRecord(substratesIndividualListgrid.getRecordIndex(record)).setAttribute(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_NAME, substratesIndividualListgrid.getRecord(substratesIndividualListgrid.getRecordIndex(record)).getAttribute(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_NAME) );
                            record.setAttribute(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_SELECTEDRADIO, 2);
                            substratesIndividualListgrid.refreshFields();
                        }
                    });

/*                    myLabel discreatLabel= new myLabel();
                    discreatLabel.setWidth(90);
                    discreatLabel.setHeight(22);
                    discreatLabel.setTop(1);
                    discreatLabel.setLeft(21);*/
                    discreatHlayout.addChild(discreatImg);
                    discreatHlayout.setSize("100px", "24px");

                    for(int i=0; i<this.getRecords().length; i++){
                        if(filldiscreatHashMap.get(i) == record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)){
                            discreatHashMap.get(record.getAttributeAsInt(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID)).selectRadio();
                        }
                    }
                    return discreatHlayout;
                }
                else{
                    return null;
                }

            }
        };
        substratesIndividualListgrid.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SIMPLE);
        substratesIndividualListgrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
        substratesIndividualListgrid.setCanEdit(true);
        substratesIndividualListgrid.setShowRecordComponents(true);
        substratesIndividualListgrid.setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true);
        ListGridField id = new myListGridField(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_ID);

        substratesIndividualListgrid.addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionEvent event) {
                if(substratesIndividualListgrid.getSelectedRecords().length>0){
                    substratesIndividualsToolStripedGrid.getDeleteDisabledIcon().hide();
                    substratesIndividualsToolStripedGrid.getDeleteEnabledIcon().show();
                }else{
                    substratesIndividualsToolStripedGrid.getDeleteDisabledIcon().show();
                    substratesIndividualsToolStripedGrid.getDeleteEnabledIcon().hide();
                }
            }
        });
        id.setType(ListGridFieldType.INTEGER);
        id.setHidden(true);

        NonEmptyValidator nonEmptyValidator = new NonEmptyValidator();
        nonEmptyValidator.setErrorMessage("cant be empty");

        //conv.colors ListGridField
        substrateIndividualName = new myListGridField(myConstants.SUBSTRATE_NAME, substratesViewVocabularies.substrateName());
        substrateIndividualName.setType(ListGridFieldType.TEXT);
        substrateIndividualName.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
        substrateIndividualName.setValidators(nonEmptyValidator);
        substrateIndividualName.setWidth(167);
        substrateIndividualName.addEditorExitHandler(this);

        convintionalFieldIndividual = new myListGridField(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_CONVENTIONAL_INDIVIDUAL, substratesViewVocabularies.conventional());
        convintionalFieldIndividual.setType(ListGridFieldType.FLOAT);
        convintionalFieldIndividual.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
        convintionalFieldIndividual.setValidators(nonEmptyValidator);
        convintionalFieldIndividual.setWidth(143);
        convintionalFieldIndividual.addChangedHandler( this);
        convintionalFieldIndividual.addEditorExitHandler(this);
        convintionalFieldIndividual.setCellFormatter(twoDigitesFormatter);

        hpFixedCostFieldIndividual = new myListGridField(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_HP_FIXED_COST_INDIVIDUAL, substratesViewVocabularies.hpFixedCost());
        hpFixedCostFieldIndividual.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
        hpFixedCostFieldIndividual.setWidth(144);
        hpFixedCostFieldIndividual.setCellFormatter(twoDigitesFormatter);

        hpPrimingFactorFieldIndividual = new myListGridField(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_HP_PRIMING_FACTOR_INDIVIDUAL, substratesViewVocabularies.hpPrimingFactor());
        hpPrimingFactorFieldIndividual.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
        hpPrimingFactorFieldIndividual.setWidth(144);
        hpPrimingFactorFieldIndividual.setCellFormatter(twoDigitesFormatter);

        hpFieldForAllDiscreteIndividual = new myListGridField(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_HP_FOR_ALL_DISCREAT_INDIVIDUAL, substratesViewVocabularies.hp());
        hpFieldForAllDiscreteIndividual.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
        hpFieldForAllDiscreteIndividual.setWidth(144);
        hpFieldForAllDiscreteIndividual.addEditorExitHandler(this);
        hpFieldForAllDiscreteIndividual.setCellFormatter(twoDigitesFormatter);
        hpFieldForAllDiscreteIndividual.setCanEdit(true);

        ListGridField suitableForInLine = new myListGridField(myConstants.SUBSTRATES_SUITABLE_FOR_IN_LINE_PRIMING_INDIVIDUAL, substratesViewVocabularies.suitableForInLinePriming());
        suitableForInLine.setType(ListGridFieldType.BOOLEAN);
        suitableForInLine.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);
        suitableForInLine.setWidth(130);

        substratesIndividualListgrid.setShowHeader(false);
        substratesIndividualListgrid.setFields(id, substrateIndividualName,convintionalFieldIndividual,hpFixedCostFieldIndividual,hpPrimingFactorFieldIndividual, hpFieldForAllDiscreteIndividual ,suitableForInLine);
        substratesIndividualListgrid.selectRecord(0);
        return substratesIndividualListgrid;
    }
```

[image]

or atleast i want away to put the text marker in the customized field